# Can I use output of one listagg query in the where clause of another listagg query

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have written a query with `listagg` like below

```
DECLARE
   v_data    VARCHAR2 (100);
   v_data2   VARCHAR2 (100);
BEGIN
   SELECT LISTAGG (data1, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY data1)
     INTO v_data
     FROM table1
    WHERE data1 IN (1, 2, 3);

   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (v_data);

   SELECT LISTAGG (data2, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY data2)
     INTO v_data2
     FROM table1
    WHERE data1 IN (v_data);

   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (v_data2);
END;
```

Can I use output of one `listagg` query in the `where` clause of another `listagg` query?

Output of v_data is `1,2,3`, so I want to use it in the 2nd query like `where data in (v_data)` i.e. `where data in(1,2,3)`

As in the above block, I am getting the output for v_data, but not v_data2.

Comment: listagg returns a varchar2 type. When you presume, that it returns you  <.. in (1,2,3) ..>, in reality it returns as <.. in ('1,2,3') ..>. If you really need to use the listagg result, build dynamic sql.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, you should *split* `V_DATA` comma-separated value into rows.

Here's an example based on Scott's schema:

```
SQL> DECLARE
  2     v_data    VARCHAR2 (100);
  3     v_data2   VARCHAR2 (100);
  4  BEGIN
  5     SELECT LISTAGG (deptno, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY deptno)
  6       INTO v_data
  7       FROM dept
  8      WHERE deptno IN (10, 20, 30);
  9
 10     DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (v_data);
 11
 12     SELECT LISTAGG (ename, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY deptno)
 13       INTO v_data2
 14       FROM emp
 15      WHERE deptno IN (select regexp_substr(v_data, '[^,]+', 1, level)
 16                       from dual
 17                       connect by level <= regexp_count(v_data, ',') + 1
 18                      );
 19
 20     DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (v_data2);
 21  END;
 22  /
10,20,30
CLARK,KING,MILLER,ADAMS,FORD,JONES,SCOTT,SMITH,ALLEN,BLAKE,JAMES,MARTIN,TURNER,WARD

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, It isn't exactly clear from your sample query as to why do you want the first `LISTAGG`.

It looks like basically this is what you are trying to do:

```
   SELECT LISTAGG (data2, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY data2)
     INTO v_data2
     FROM table1
    WHERE data1 IN ( select data1 from table1  where .. );--some other where clause
```